# Is the expression "as is easy to see" correct?

Tags: grammar

I am reading a math article, and I encounter the expression *as is easy to see*.

First I thought it was a typo, but then I encountered it several other times.

So I came here to ask: is the expression *as is easy to see* grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @BillJ I am used to hearing _as it is easy to see_...

Comment: I see. All that has happened is that the pronoun "it" (the subject of the clause "is easy to see") is ellipted. The pronoun is anaphoric to some previously mentioned fact, i.e. the 'understood' missing subject.

Comment: Also commonly heard is "as can easily be seen", again with a missing subject.

Comment: "As is obvious/straightforward/apparent," are okay, too.  And "as can easily be shown/as we shall now demonstrate".  There is no "it".  The function is that of a sentence adverb,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A parenthetical "as is [adjectival or nominal complement]" is very common, more in written than spoken English, I think.

The GloWbE corpus has over seven thousand instances of "as is [adjective]", (though some of them are the different construction "as [adjective] as is [adjective]", for example "as much as is easy for you").

Only eleven of them are "as is easy", and as it happens, none of these is "as is easy to see". But it does have "as is easy to show" and "as is easy to perceive".

**Edit**: prompted by E Joseph's and BillJ's comments, I looked for instances of "as it is [adjective]" in the corpus (which is not a construction I would use myself in this way). At first sight there are more instances (192 of "as it is easy"), but nearly all of them are a different construction with an object, eg "as it is easy to see the glass as half empty". There are no instances of "as it is easy to see" in the GloWbE corpus with the required meaning.

Comment: But the OP is asking about the missing "it".

Comment: @BillJ. The OP might be asking about the missing 'it'. But since the OP makes no mention anywhere of "it", I don't see how you can assert that. To me, there is no missing 'it': on the contrary, an 'it' would be intrusive.

Comment: 'As can easily be seen' needs rather more faith in the ellipting of an 'it'.

Comment: He mentions it as being  his concern in his comment to me.

Comment: @BillJ The expression _as is easy to see_ sounded odd to me, and I thought it was missing an _it_. But the answer of ColinFine is great, and the expression I perceive the more natural is the one of EdwinAshworth _as can easily be seen_.

Comment: @E.Joseph "As can easily be seen"  was the example that I too gave in my 3rd comment to you.